# Multiple Select Count in Different Condition

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have table that contain clients_status, and my query just like these:

```
SELECT ROUND((SUM(client_status='BAD DEBT')/COUNT(*))*100) AS BAD, 
       ROUND((SUM(client_status='ALERT')/COUNT(*))*100) AS ALERT, 
       ROUND((SUM(client_status='REMIND BAYAR')/COUNT(*))*100) AS REMIND, 
       ROUND((SUM(client_status='RUTIN BAYAR')/COUNT(*))*100) AS RUTIN, 
       ROUND((SUM(client_status='POTENSI KOREKSI')/COUNT(*))*100) AS POTENSI, 
       ROUND((SUM(client_status='TOP 10')/COUNT(*))*100) AS TOP FROM clients
```

And the output of my query just like this: 
[image]

What should i do, to make my output like this:

```
Data     value
=============== 
Bad      29
Alert    29
Remind   14
Rutin    14
Potensi  0
Top      15
```

Please help guys... thanks,

Comment: You could change each of those lines to their own select and `UNION` them instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate grouping by the status and cross join a subquery getting the total count to calculate the percentage. For the renaming and the custom order you can use `CASE`s.

```
SELECT cs.s data,
       cs.c / ca.c * 100 value
       FROM (SELECT CASE client_status
                      WHEN 'BAD DEPT' THEN
                        1
                      WHEN 'ALERT' THEN
                        2
                      WHEN 'REMIND BAYAR' THEN
                        2
                      WHEN 'RUTIN BAYAR' THEN
                        4
                      WHEN 'POTENSI KOREKSI' THEN
                        5
                      WHEN 'TOP 10' THEN
                        6
                    END o,
                    CASE client_status
                      WHEN 'BAD DEPT' THEN
                        'Bad'
                      WHEN 'ALERT' THEN
                        'Alert'
                      WHEN 'REMIND BAYAR' THEN
                        'Remind'
                      WHEN 'RUTIN BAYAR' THEN
                        'Rutin'
                      WHEN 'POTENSI KOREKSI' THEN
                        'Potensi'
                      WHEN 'TOP 10' THEN
                        'Top'
                   END s,
                   count(*) c
                   FROM clients
                   GROUP BY client_status) cs
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT count(*) c
                               FROM clients) ca
       ORDER BY cs.o;
```